# Pinterest type image gallery

Tags: ajax, image, jquery, picturebox, picturegallery

I am looking for a ajax based image gallery that would load contents of  php file similar to

> pinterest.com

.

When we click on the thumbnail image then without reloading the page a new div element is created contain the image along the html/ php page

Comment: just reload the new content with ajax....

Comment: @ThreeDev - But this is not happening on pinterest.com  . There is some special effect that doesnt reload the page.it seems like it is being enlarged moreover when we click outside of the box the original page appears.

Comment: so load all the content in the begining and hide it until you mouse hover :)

Comment: @ThreeDev - But that would not be possible for a page containing 50-60 images :)

Comment: why not? do it asynchronus... from the latest data to the older data...

Comment: This isn't the shopping channel. Got a SPECIFIC code question?